# Numpy IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, index-error

I'm trying to run my code using python 2.7, and OpenCV 3.3, but I`m running into the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "CameraTest.py",
>   line 52, in 
>       height = np.size(Frame,0)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line
>   2700, in size
>       return asarray(a).shape[axis] IndexError: tuple index out of range

These are some of the code lines:

```
47 for i in range(0,20):
48    (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read(), 0
49
50 while True:
51  (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read(), 0
52  height = np.size(Frame,0)
53  width = np.size(Frame,1)
54  if not grabbed:
55      break
56
57  frame = camera.read()
58  frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
```

Also read what the fromnumeric.py file had to say, and have no clue to what is my problem, I'm really lost in my Python here, been struggling with this error for some days now, and I couldn't find the answer by myself or searching. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `print(Frame)`?  It seem you're assigning int `0` to `Frame`.

Comment: I may have got that very wrong, but I assingned 0 to frame because for i in range(0,20):
   (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read() without the 0 was giving too many values to unpack error, expected 2

Comment: And the for loop is irrelevant to this error, in your first for loop you tried to assign whatever `camera.read()` is and 0 to grabbed and Framed for 20 times. Note that only the final time counts. And then in the while loop you're doing this again, except it fails after the first time since `0` does not have a shape. The for loops did not accomplish anything as you overwrote `grabbed, Frame` first thing in your while loop.

Comment: I'll look out for that Rocky, I need some more python experience, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always setting `Frame` to 0

```
(grabbed, Frame) = camera.read(), 0
```

`grabbed` gets output of `camera.read()` and `Frame` gets 0.  For and `int`, `np.size` returns 1.

Comment: Tried that right now, it gives out :    height = np.size(Frame)[0]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: What does `type(Frame)` return?  It sounds like it is an `int` and not `np.array`.  Therefore, `np.size` returns 1.

Comment: Here is the full code, I suspect I made some many mistakes around it... https://pastebin.com/GuPHVnSq

Comment: You are always setting `Frame` to 0

Comment: Thing is, if I remove the 0 in (grabbed, Frame) = camera.read(), I get ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Did that, I get no unpack error it's now like 1=1 but it then becomes     height = np.size(Frame)[0]
NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined, since it's removed from the unpack error.

Comment: Yes, `Frame` no longer exists, so it should be `np.size(grabbed)`.

Comment: Thanks man, I will continue from now to solve the remaining errors! =)

Comment: Okay, got everything to work! cleaned some redundancies of the code aswell, following @Rocky Li 's advice and added some new functionality like writing to a file and sending it via email. Here it is: [link](https://pastebin.com/f5Z4eBC7)